# how to opendoor effect in animation css opens right to left?

Tags: css, css-animations

Is it possible to opendoor animation css opens right to left.

[here](http://bootsnipp.com/snippets/nPZ4N) is an example that opens left to right.

```
.slideshow .overlay-item  {
    position: absolute;
    top: 0;
    right:0;
    z-index: 999;
    width: 360px;
    background: rgba(248, 148, 6, 0.67);
    height: 400px;
    padding: 10px 30px;
    display: none;
    -webkit-animation: opendoor 0.75s ease 0s alternate;
    -webkit-transform-style: preserve-3d;
            transform-style: preserve-3d;
}
```

Comment: @Serg Chernata it was not funny

Comment: Try to ask "how can I" next time, and not whether it's just possible

Answer (score 1, accepted):

Change the `opendoor` animation as follows:

```
@-webkit-keyframes opendoor {
    from {
        -webkit-transform: perspective(1000px) rotateY(-90deg);
        -webkit-transform-origin: 100% 50%;
    }
    to {
        -webkit-transform: perspective(1000px) rotateY(0deg);
        -webkit-transform-origin: 100% 50%;
    }
}
```

And the `closedoor`animation accordingly:

```
@-webkit-keyframes closedoor {
    from {
        opacity:1;
        -webkit-transform-origin: 100% 50%;
    }
    to {
        opacity:0;
        -webkit-transform-origin: 100% 50%;
    }
}
```

Demo here:
http://www.bootply.com/Te5VrShLV5.

Answer (score 1):

The "-webkit-animation: opendoor" part of the code refers to the CSS keyframes animation. You will need to edit that part of the code. Something like this will work:

```
@-webkit-keyframes opendoor {
    from {
        -webkit-transform: perspective(1000px) rotateY(90deg);
        -webkit-transform-origin: 100% 0%;
    }
    to {
        -webkit-transform: perspective(1000px) rotateY(0deg);
        -webkit-transform-origin: 100% 0%;
    }
}
```

You'll need to edit the "closedoor" animation as well.